# How to parse the JKS (Java KeyStore) file using openSSL?

Tags: openssl, x509, jks

How to parse the `JKS` (Java KeyStore) using openSSL?
I found the `pkcs12_parse` method to parse `p12` files but not `jks` files.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that `OpenSSL` has a facility to read Java Keystore (JKS) files. If you can run `keytool` on your platform, you should be able to convert the whole `JKS` file to `PKCS12`, which is supported by openssl:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore foo.jks -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore foo.p12
```

I appreciate that this will be awkward if it has to be done on-device on Android.